# Custom inputformat to process protobufs in hadoop 0.20

Tags: hadoop, protocol-buffers

I'd like to process protobufs using hadoop....but am unsure where to start.
I don't care about splitting large files.
The protobufs are stored as binary data...what class should I extend to make it easier

Answer (score 1):

[elephant-bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) can process protobufs using hadoop. This framework generates hadoop I/O classes along with regular protobuf classes. It uses lzo compression.

Comment: Figured out a way to do it by extending: FileInputFormat and RecordReader. Had to dig into hadoop source code to get an idea...but things work great now...

Comment: @grifin griffin - why don't you share your solution with the rest of us?