# Working with Protobuf and Hive

Tags: protocol-buffers, hive

I am new to Protobuf and Hive. I am trying to store protobufs in Hive and seem to be having issues with new lines in my protobuf. I see that the user Griffin has had success in doing this.

[Custom inputformat to process protobufs in hadoop 0.20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254281/custom-inputformat-to-process-protobufs-in-hadoop-0-20)

Can you please give me more details on doing this? I have tried ElephantBird and Hive-protobuf both of which work with Sequencefiles and I don't have my protobuf in sequence file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hive-protobuf` does handle this situation for me. With no other options, I had to convert my `protobufs` to `Sequencefiles` and now I am able to work with a `Hive SerDe`.